# inject the same @SessionScoped Bean in different @Named Beans

Tags: jsf, cdi

I have a little javaee webproject and i need bean injection in it. i have a tomee server with cdi enabled. Here is a little test case.

Here is my @SessionScoped User object

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;

@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable {
    String userName;

    public User () {}
    public User (String userName) { this.userName = userName; }

    public String getUserName() { return userName; }
    public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName; }
}
```

and here are my two nearly identical beans:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class BeanOne {
    private String message;
    @Inject User user;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { user = new User("TestName"); }

    public String getMessage() { return user.getUserName(); }
}
```

In this bean i create a new user. the method getMessage returns the correct user name. I thought the user should still exist in the second bean because its @SessionScoped. Here is my second bean.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class BeanTwo {
    private String message;
    @Inject User user;      

    public String getMessage() { return user.getUserName(); }
}
```

But in this bean the user.getUserName() returns null. How am i supposed to inject a @SessionScoped bean?

Comment: Just curious why this was voted down? I think it's a great question. Voted back up :)

Comment: I am new to java-ee but to critique my research effort is just plain wrong. I researched this for hours, the documentation of everything releated to java-ee is non-existant or very hard to understand if you have no prior knowledge and annotations are "magic". why should this work only because i use @Produces which is just antoher annotation, but it does work. So please dont just assume things you cant possibly know BalusC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have manually initialized `user` object in `BeanOne` init method. The purpose of dependency injection is to let some container create instances of objects for you, so you should never initialize objects manually. So just set a name for this user and it will be visible during session for all other beans.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() { user.setUserName("TestName"); }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. And it also works with a @Produces method.